# Upload File with unknown size OneDrive

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

So I am uploading a file to one drive using a resumable file upload session. However I cannot know the size of the file before uploading. I know that google allows uploading of files with content ranges like

```
Content-Range: 0-128/*
```

I would assume OneDrive would also allow it as it is even specified in RFC2616

> Content-Range = "Content-Range" ":" content-range-spec
>
> ```
>    content-range-spec      = byte-content-range-spec
>    byte-content-range-spec = bytes-unit SP
>                              byte-range-resp-spec "/"
>                              ( instance-length | "*" )
>
>    byte-range-resp-spec = (first-byte-pos "-" last-byte-pos)
>                                   | "*"
>    instance-length           = 1*DIGIT
> ```
>
> The header SHOULD indicate the total length of the full
>   entity-body,    unless this length is unknown or difficult to
>   determine. The asterisk    "*" character means that the
>   instance-length is unknown at the time    when the response was
>   generated.

But after reading the OneDrive documentation I found it says

> Example: In this example, the app is uploading the first 26 bytes of a
>   128 byte file.
>
> The Content-Length header specifies the size of the current request.
>
> The Content-Range header indicates the range of bytes in the overall
>   file that this request represents.
>
> **The total length of the file is**
>   known before you can upload the first fragment of the file. HTTP
>
> ```
> Copy PUT https://sn3302.up.1drv.com/up/fe6987415ace7X4e1eF866337
> Content-Length: 26 Content-Range: bytes 0-25/128
>
> <bytes 0-25 of the file>
> ```
>
> Important: Your app must ensure the total
>   file size specified in the Content-Range header is the same for all
>   requests. If a byte range declares a different file size, the request
>   will fail.

Maybe I'm just reading the documentation wrong or it only applies to this example but before I go and build a entire uploader I would just like clarification if this is allowed for OneDrive

**My Question is**

Does OneDrive allow uploading of files with unknown sizes?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else wondering, no you can't, file uploads must specify a size.